# wxFileSystemWatcher C++. Delete event FILE or FOLDER?

Tags: wxwidgets, filesystemwatcher

Is there a way of identifying if the deleted entity is a file or a folder on the delete notification from wxFileSystemWathcer?

Comment: Have you tried to search on Google??

Answer (score 0):

No, you should be maintaining your own list of existing directories and check if the name of the object being deleted is in it, if this is important to you.

Notice that, generally speaking, `wxFileSystemWatcher` gives you information about the changes to the state which you are supposed to keep internally. It won't allow you to recreate this state itself, only (incremental) updates to it.